# Plotting two-series bar chart in python in a single expression

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a bar chart with two series from raw data. My data looks like this:

[image]

So what I want to do is group by prev_purchase_count, count unique customers, and split/colour by segment.

I've written a few lines of code which achieve what I want to do but **I know there is an easier way** - probably one line.

```
lv_purch = df_customers.loc[df_customers['segment']=='low-value','prev_purchase_count']
hv_purch = df_customers.loc[df_customers['segment']=='high-value','prev_purchase_count']
plt.hist([lv_purch,hv_purch], label=['low-value','high-value'])
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image: Desired Output]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.countplot(x='prev_purchase_count', hue = 'segment', data=df_customers)
plt.legend(loc='upper right'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use df.groupby(['prev_purchase_count']) to group them according to low or high

Comment: Can you give an example of a particular function? For example, I tried 
ax = sns.barplot(x='prev_purchase_count', hue='segment', data=df_customers)